# constructor initialization list execution order with delegated constructors

Tags: list, constructor, initialization

I have a tricky C++ question: When you have a constructor initialization list with delegated constructors, what is the list execution order?

There exist two conflicting standard rules here:
1.) The constructor initialization list gets executed NOT by the list order but by the declaration order of the items.
2.) Delegated constructors in the constructor initialization list always get called before the "mother constructor" is executed.

Which rule is superior? (since a constructor is a class item too)
Why this is important: assume the delegated constructor re-inits an item already initialized by the "mother constructor" or vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

§12.6.2/6 says

> If a *mem-initializer-id* designates the constructor’s class,
>   it shall be the only *mem-initializer*... Once the target constructor returns, the body of the
>   delegating constructor is executed.

So there's no conflict, since you can't initialise anything before you delegate a constructor. Delegating a constructor simply calls that constructor, the target constructor's initialiser list is run, the target constructor runs, and then the principal constructor runs.

Comment: Thanks - but to be honest I do not understand how your statement follows from your quoted text. If it is correct and I understand it right, this means:
1)exec the delegated constructors list
2)exec the delegated constructors body
3)exec the principal constructors list
4)exec the principal constructors body

Comment: @BM no, it's just 1)exec the delegated constructors list 2)exec the delegated constructors body 3)exec the principal constructors body. The principal constructor can't have an initialiser list other than delegating the constructor, as the quote indicates.

Comment: *narf* I get it now - I wanted to use re-init through list as feature - but I reckon it would be a dangerous one. Thanks alot!

Comment: @BM I don't know exactly what you mean, but remember that you can do `struct S { int x = 0; };` and any variables initialised in the init-lists will not be initialised with the values you use in the declaration.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately my problem is more complex: I have a member object that can be of different types and thus can have different constructors, which again have non-static parameters. So I do need to use the init-list only to init that object and I have different "parent constructors" to handle the possible object constructors.