# C++ delegating constructor with initialization list. Which inits happen?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, definition, delegating-constructor

I've looked at [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857825/constructor-initialization-list-execution-order-with-delegated-constructors), but I'm not quite sure I understand the answer. If I delegate a constructor, which initializations from initialization lists occur?

Example:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int a, int b)
:
MyClass(a, b, NULL),
int1(a),
int2(b),
pOtherClass(NULL)
{
}

MyClass::MyClass(int a, int b, Other *p)
:
int1(a),
int2(b),
pOtherClass(p)
{
     if (pOtherClass == NULL)
     {
         pOtherClass = &DefaultInstance;
     }
}
```

Here I have to have full initializer lists for both classes due to compiler settings. But what I **don't** want is:

1. First constructor(`int, int`) calls the second constructor(`int, int, Other *`)
2. Second constructor assigns a default address to `pOtherClass`
3. First constructor's init list assigns `pOtherClass` to `NULL`.

The question I linked at the top seems to indicate that this behavior **wont** occur, but then what is the point of the initializer list in the (`int, int`) constructor? Just to keep the compiler happy?

Comment: This is invalid code, as the other answer states and as the [compiler shows](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c899f8e5a49a9bce).

Comment: hrmmmm, when I have the delegate alone I get errors about members not being present in the init list. As well as `error: MyClass is not a direct base of MyClass`.  Perhaps this indicates that we don't use c++11 though, that could be the issue.

Comment: It could be that your compiler doesn't support delegating constructors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard

> If a mem-initializer-id designates the constructor’s class, **it shall be
>   the only mem-initializer;** the constructor is a delegating constructor,
>   and the constructor selected by the mem-initializer is the target
>   constructor. The principal constructor is the first constructor
>   invoked in the construction of an object (that is, not a target
>   constructor for that object’s construction). The target constructor is
>   selected by overload resolution. Once the target constructor returns,
>   the body of the delegating constructor is executed. If a constructor
>   delegates to itself directly or indirectly, the program is ill-formed;
>   no diagnostic is required.

So this constructor definition

```
MyClass::MyClass(int a, int b)
:
MyClass(a, b, NULL),
int1(a),
int2(b),
pOtherClass(NULL)
{
}
```

is invalid.

Must be

```
MyClass::MyClass(int a, int b)
:
MyClass(a, b, NULL)
{
}
```